# Webkit Color Transition Loop on text doesn't work in firefox

Tags: css

I want my H3 tags to change color in an infinite loop. My code works fine in Safari but Firefox isn't making the tag change color?

Here is my code:

```
    h3 {color: #333 !important;}
@-webkit-keyframes colours {
      0% {color: #333;}
     15% {color: #8bc5d1;}
     30% {color: #f8cb4a;}
     45% {color: #95b850;}
     60% {color: #944893;}
     75% {color: #c71f00;}
     90% {color: #bdb280;}
    100% {color: #333;}
}
h3 {
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: colours;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Comment: All those `webkit` directives? They only apply to Safari. Firefox ignores them. There are corresponding `moz` (Mozilla) tags for Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `-webkit` prefix, which will only work in webkit enabled browsers. You can add the non-prefixed versions to support modern browsers that support the syntax, and you can also add the prefixed versions for all browsers.

```css
h3 {
  color: #333;
}


@-webkit-keyframes colours {
  0% {
    color: #333;
  }
  15% {
    color: #8bc5d1;
  }
  30% {
    color: #f8cb4a;
  }
  45% {
    color: #95b850;
  }
  60% {
    color: #944893;
  }
  75% {
    color: #c71f00;
  }
  90% {
    color: #bdb280;
  }
  100% {
    color: #333;
  }
}


@keyframes colours {
  0% {
    color: #333;
  }
  15% {
    color: #8bc5d1;
  }
  30% {
    color: #f8cb4a;
  }
  45% {
    color: #95b850;
  }
  60% {
    color: #944893;
  }
  75% {
    color: #c71f00;
  }
  90% {
    color: #bdb280;
  }
  100% {
    color: #333;
  }
}

h3 {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
          animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
          animation-duration: 60s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours;
          animation-name: colours;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<h3>foo</h3>
```